# BER of OQPSK Modulation

Tags: matlab, modulation, dsp-core

I am unable to find out a formula for the BER for the OQPSK Modulation. Currently, I am using the berawgn function from Matlab to calculate the BER for OQPSK but I am looking for an expression for this BER. Pointers to any references would be appreciated

Comment: The BER for QPSK and OQPSK is the same as the BER for BPSK for a given energy per _bit_ to noise density ratio $E_b/N_0$.

Comment: Doesn't the BER change since OQPSK uses 2 bits per symbol? Does it mean that BER is 0.5*erfc(sqrt(Eb/2*No) ?

Comment: B = bit in the abbreviation BER. QPSK and OQPSK are effectively _two_ BPSK channels operating separately and each achieves the BER of the BPSK signal. **Do not** confuse between the _symbol_ error probability and the _SNR_ which might be stated as $E_s/N_0$ (where $E_s$ is the _energy per symbol_) and the BER and BEND ratio $E_b/N_0$ (BEND = bit energy to noise density).

Comment: In the implementation of DSSS OQPSK modulation, for the computation of BER, I am using the following expression: BER=0.5*erfc(sqrt((10^(SNR/10))/2)); whereas  with a processing gain of 9 dB, BER = 0.5*erfc(sqrt((10^(SNR+ (10*log10(8))/10))/2)); Am I making a mistake here?